# how to keep trigger background color when textview change in onchangedlistner android

Tags: java, android

`enter code here`In android java how to keep trigger background color when textview change in onchangedlistner android like suppose
i have getting number getting live number 49500 if it increase then change background with green color and if decrease it will change with red color in back ground and if nothing happening then color remains same as before in background

i am getting live data from firebase

Thank you if any help apricated
here is my code pls help me if possible thank you

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rateviwe = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live_rate, container, false);

```
    gold9999 = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.gold9999id);
    gold9950 = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.gold9950id);
    silver9999 = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silver9999id);
    silver9950 = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silver9950id);
    mcxgoldbuy = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldmcxbuyid);
    mcxgoldsell = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldmcxsellid);
    mcxgoldhighlow = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldmcxhiglowid);
    mcxsilverbuy = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvermcxbuyid);
    mcxsilversell = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvermcxsellid);
    mcxsilverhighlow = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvermcxhighlowid);

    goldcomexbuy = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldcomexbuyid);
    goldcomexsell = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldcomexsellid);
    goldcomexhighlow = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.goldcomexhighlowid);
    silvercomexbuy = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvercomexbuyid);
    silvercomexsell = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvercomexsellid);
    silvercomexhighlow = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.silvercomexhighlowid);

    inrcomexbuy = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.inrcomexbuyid);
    inrcomexsell = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.inrcomexsellid);
    inrcomexhighlow = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.inrcomexhighlowid);
    marquetext = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.marqueeText);

    swipeRefreshLayout = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
    mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    scrollView = rateviwe.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    marquetext.setSelected(true);


    gold9999.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String one=gold9999.toString();
                String two=charSequence.toString();
```

//                int color = i1>i ? R.color.green : R.color.red;
//                gold9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color));

```
          /*  if (!(one ==two)) {

                goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#242B2E"));
            } else {

                goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
            }*/

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }
    });

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            try {

                    onStart();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });


    return rateviwe;
}




    @Override
    public void onStart () {
    super.onStart();


    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {


            String gold9999rate = dataSnapshot.child("gold9999").getValue().toString();
            String gold9950rate = dataSnapshot.child("gold9950").getValue().toString();

            String silver9999rate = dataSnapshot.child("silver9999").getValue().toString();
            String silver9950rate = dataSnapshot.child("silver99").getValue().toString();

            String goldcomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexbuy").getValue().toString();
            String goldcomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexsell").getValue().toString();
            String goldcomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexhigh").getValue().toString();
            String goldcomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexlow").getValue().toString();

            String silvercomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexbuy").getValue().toString();
            String silvercomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexsell").getValue().toString();
            String silvercomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexhigh").getValue().toString();
            String silvercomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexlow").getValue().toString();

            String inrcomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexbuy").getValue().toString();
            String inrcomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexsell").getValue().toString();
            String inrcomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexhigh").getValue().toString();
            String inrcomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexlow").getValue().toString();

            String goldmcxbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxbuy").getValue().toString();
            String goldmcxsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxsell").getValue().toString();
            String goldmcxhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxhigh").getValue().toString();
            String goldmcxlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxlow").getValue().toString();

            String silvermcxbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxbuy").getValue().toString();
            String silvermcxsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxsell").getValue().toString();
            String silvermcxhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxhigh").getValue().toString();
            String silvermcxlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxlow").getValue().toString();

            gold9999.setText(gold9999rate);
            gold9950.setText(gold9950rate);

            silver9999.setText(silver9999rate);
            silver9950.setText(silver9950rate);
            goldcomexbuy.setText(goldcomexbuyrate);



           /* if (!goldcomexbuyrate.isEmpty()) {
                goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));

            } else {
                goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#242B2E"));
            } */

            goldcomexsell.setText(goldcomexsellrate);

            goldcomexhighlow.setText(goldcomexhighrate + "/" + goldcomexlowrate);

            silvercomexbuy.setText(silvercomexbuyrate);
            silvercomexsell.setText(silvercomexsellrate);
            silvercomexhighlow.setText(silvercomexhighrate + "/" + silvercomexlowrate);

            inrcomexbuy.setText(inrcomexbuyrate);
            inrcomexsell.setText(inrcomexsellrate);
            inrcomexhighlow.setText(inrcomexhighrate + "/" + inrcomexlowrate);

            mcxgoldbuy.setText(goldmcxbuyrate);
            mcxgoldsell.setText(goldmcxsellrate);
            mcxgoldhighlow.setText(goldmcxhighrate + "/" + goldmcxlowrate);

            mcxsilverbuy.setText(silvermcxbuyrate);
            mcxsilversell.setText(silvermcxsellrate);
            mcxsilverhighlow.setText(silvermcxhighrate + "/" + silvermcxlowrate);




        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();


        }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("TAP","something wrong");
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Internet connection. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setMargin(50,50);
                toast.show();

            }
        });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this where you save previous value and check if your number decreases or increases.
But you should provide your code for better answer.

```
 int savedLastItem = 49500;
 yourObjectLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), object -> 
    if(object>savedLastItem){
    textView.setBackground(<yourColor>);
    } else if (object<savedLastItem) {
    textView.setBackground(<yourColor>);
    }          
    savedLastItem = object; //if you need to save last number
            });
```

Comment: please look now i added code